# I am trying to deploying my static react app on github pages but i'm getting white screen

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

**After taking a look at console, i got this**

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://abhishek-098.github.io/TourSpot%20/static/js/2.1f6fc1d5.chunk.js”.
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://abhishek-098.github.io/TourSpot%20/static/js/main.3961266e.chunk.js”.
```

Link to my Repo : https://github.com/Abhishek-098/TourSpot

Comment: What is your name of repo? If you create repo as "Test", then your project's base url has to be https://abhishek-098.github.io/Test.

In Angular i easily can set it in index.html meta tag.

Comment: just posted it, have a look

Comment: and you would like to see it as a html page?

Comment: i'm new to react , so everything is new to me. if i'm wrong at any place please correct me.

Comment: According to https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/ you should have build/static folder, but your repo doesn't contains. How you build your react app in production mode? I see package.json and node_modules folder what is unnecessary in a production build. I think you build it incorrectly

Comment: okay thanks. i will do it again. BTW i was following the exact same steps as my tutor did on Youtube.

Comment: I think after build you have to upload static folder to repo. 
https://miro.medium.com/max/2268/1*7KBGbk5IiX5JPoL1rmNcjw.png 
After that maybe we can fix some thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229626/discussion-between-peter-and-abhishek-chauhan).

Comment: yup sure, i am just doing what you said. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deploying a Single-Page Application (React, Vue) to GitHub Pages, you should know that it is necessary that you do a production build. This can be accomplished by doing `npm run build` or `yarn build` depending on the package manager you are using. This command will generate a `./dist` or `./build` folder that will contain your react app in pure HTML, CSS, and JS.

For GitHub pages, there are some configurations you should do. First of all, the index.html from your production build (from the dist, build folder) should be in the root folder, which means, you should be able to see it when you open the repo (not inside the build folder). If GitHub pages do not detect any index.html in the root of the repo, it will display a 404 page.

Now, since you do not want the production build files messing around with your React project, it is recommended that you create a different branch for your GitHub pages deploy.

So, ideally, you would have two branches: master and gh-pages, the first one containing your React project and the second one containing only your dist folder but in the root of the project.

Here is an example of the structure of a Repo that it's deployed using GitHub pages.

https://github.com/8rb/React-Quiz/tree/master

You can see both branches and the deployment link works perfectly fine.
To configure the branch that is being deployed to GitHub pages, go to settings and select the branch where you have your production build.

[image: gh-pages settings]

All the information was taken for the following link:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages

I hope you found it useful!

Comment: He created a new repo: https://github.com/Abhishek-098/React_Project

There is a master and a gh-pages branch. He said that GitHub page's source set to gh-pages branch. what else is missing?

Answer (score 0):

@Rodrigo Ramirez does explain how its done, but leaves out some important information provided in the docs he linked (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages). Maybe the've been updated since but I would recommend following those steps in the doc. They give step by step instructions that are very easy to follow.

I tried following @Rodrigo Ramirez answer, as well as, countless other things on the internet and nothing worked and it was all very complicated. The doc provided here gets it all done for you very easily.